# What's the difference between Epson's 001, 003, and 101 ink codes?

Tags: inkjet-printer, epson-ecotank

The title says it all. What's the difference between Epson's 001, 003, and 101 ink codes?

All I know is 001 inks are pigment-based and 003 inks are dye-based. This becomes more confusing when the printer specs like L6190 says it is using pigment for black and dye for colors when all the included ink bottles are 001.

What do these codes mean?